# calling python function with multiple argument in C#

Tags: c#, python

I am stuck with a problem. I have created a simple python code say for summing 2 variables. File is called as Addition.py.

Addition.py

```
import sys
import math
def ad(a,b):
    print(a+b)
```

I have created a separate C# wpf code and now I am trying to run Additional.py file with a c# application with below mentioned code. I have tried to pass 2 argument for adding value but still in myString variable I get null value. I do not get any error or any exception while executing code.

```
public void finalMethod()
    {
        string pyt = @"C:\Python34\python.exe";
        int x = 2;
        int y = 5;

        string myPyt = @"D:\Addition.py"; 
        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pyt);

        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPyt + " " + x + " " + y;

        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;

        myProcess.Start();

        StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
        string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine();

        myProcess.WaitForExit();
        myProcess.Close();

        lblText.Content = myString;
    }
```

My purpose is simple that my main code is written in C# but I have a lot of math formulas which I want to write in python and than want to call those function based on process requirement.

Comment: but you're not even parsing the arguments in your python example...

Comment: Since you are tightly coupled with .Net, why not use ironpython (http://ironpython.net/). You can compile to a dll that is directly consumable to .Net, and is supported in Visual Studio

Comment: You should show all of the relevant parts  of the Python.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Francois. solution given by you worked. but I am still wondering why you removed it. wanted to give positive ratings.

Comment: @SteveJ Hello SteveJ, I must say I am new to programming world but still I tried to implement the code the way you described. I created a ironpython code and compiled it to a dll with help of clr.CompileModule. I added this dll as a reference in another C#wpf project. but in C#wpf project I am not able to see the function made inside python project. Can you please explain me how it should work. Thanks

Comment: @braveYug; Perhaps this link will help; https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2009/10/25/running-ironpython-scripts-from-a-c-4-0-program/

Comment: @SteveJ; Thanks Steve it worked +1 from me. But now i ran into a different problem. I want to lock my python file that no one should be able to see the python code or change it. For this i compiled .py file to .pyc file(bytecode). but C# compiler doesn't recognize .pyc. My main task is to lock .py files so that no one can open it or see inside it. Any suggestion?

Comment: @braveYug; Better to start a new thread for a new question. If you can't find your answer immediately on SO, there are lots of python Gurus that can help you that are much more qualified than I. However, the truth is that is a losing battle in any language. If someone wants it badly enough, they will get at it. If you don't want someone to see your code, put it behind a web service. Though why? -- there is nothing you are doing that someone else hasn't likely done or couldn't figure out. If not, publish it and get the recognition you deserve.